# Retrieving data from MySQL with AngularJS and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, electron

first of all, perhaps I need to clarify that I'm new with this kind of technologies. I'm migrating from PHP to JavaScript and I've never made this kind of work before. I'm making a desktop app with Electron + AngularJS. I have a simple table where I need to show the fetched MySQL table data. Looking information I found a simple way to do it with NodeJS, but I have problems storing de retrieved data to the $scope to after, show that with the ng-repeat directive. This my code (simplyfied):

```
app.controller('registrosController', function($scope, $http) {
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: null,
        database: 'dniscan'
    })
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err.stack);
        }
    })
    $queryString = 'SELECT * FROM registros ORDER BY escaneado DESC';
    connection.query($queryString, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return console.log("Ocurrió un error durante la consulta", err)
        }
        console.log(data)       //The data shows correctly in the console.
        $scope.registros = data //This not working. It returns undefined.
    });
    connection.end();
});
```

Comment: Isn't angular running in the browser? If it is you will not be able to run SQL queries directly.

Comment: So your  {{registros}} shows as undefined?

Comment: Yes @petul, I tried {{ registros }} and {{ registros | json }} and nothing appeared.

Comment: Might be a scope issue, as registros is defined inside the query function

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are mixing up client and server, so to clarify, in the server you get the data from the db. In the client you put the data on the scope. Then in the HTML you put the data from the scope in the view.

Here is an example:

> Server - NodeJs

```
app.get('getData', function (req, res) {
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... });
    connection.connect((err, connection) => {
        if(err) { 
            res.send({ err }) 
        } else {
            var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM ...';

            connection.query(queryString, (err, data) => {
                if(err) { 
                    res.send({ err }) 
                } else {
                    res.send({ data });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    connection.end();
});
```

> Client - AngularJs

```
app.controller('registrosController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/getData').then(function(data) {
        $scope.registros = data;
    });
});
```

> Client - Html

```
<div ng-repeat="registro in registros">
    ...
</div>
```

P.S. in javascript you don't define a variable by appending it with a `$`, but by the word `var`.

Comment: Thank you very much @RabbiShuki for your answer and corrections. I'm trying your code but don't understand where the get function comes from. When I test the app, the console log returns _Uncaught TypeError: app.get is not a function_

Comment: The get is from express, if you have it installed with node.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use mysql from a browser. Code which you're running is fine for Node(it being a server side platform) it will access your (server)'s mysql and store data there.

if you want to store some persistent data in browser, best way to do that is local storage or session storage which are features of HTML5 and will be accessible until a user deletes them.

However if you really want to use database, which i wouldn't recommend. there are some light database available for that.

from my search i could find sqlite package for angular :- https://github.com/reduardo7/angular-sqlite

also you can use indexddb which is document based database :- 
https://github.com/webcss/angular-indexedDB

Answer (score -2):

You should be using angular.copy to move the data into $scope.registros

```
$scope.registros = angular.copy(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mark S. but I still have the same problem and the same results.

Comment: After that line of code, if you print out $scope.registros in a console.log, then is the data showing?

Comment: angular.copy is for duplicating an object, not for using it.